# How to get all named branches part of a specific changeset

Tags: mercurial

Given

```
---a----b----c----d----e----f (default)
     |  |           |  
     ---g (1.0)     ----h---i---(2.0)
```

I want to know, for a specific changeset, which named branches (releases in my case) that this changeset is part of (a parent of the head of the named branch).

input -> output

- a -> default, 1.0, 2.0
- g -> default, 1.0, 2.0
- d -> default, 2.0
- e -> default
- h -> 2.0

How can I do this the easiest way (something with hg log ancestors I guess?)? I would prefer not taking the branch names as input but dynamically using all (open) named branches.

Answer (score 1):

For others having the same question as myself...

I found the extension contains, https://bitbucket.org/resi/hg-contains, which does exactly what I want.

```
hg headscontaining -b --revno [changesetId] --template {branches}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[revsetalias]
bd($1) = descendants($1) - branch(default)
```

In use: `hg bd(CSET-ID)`

Edit: Well, my initial version was better than needed (and not usable) - it returned list of branches immediately, which may be hardly used as revset in final Mercurial commands.

With single operation result is **revset for using in templated log**

`hg log -r "bd(CSET)" --template "{branch}\n"`

Comment: Thanks. Probably just lack of hg knowledge from my side but... If I add this revsetalias I still can't execute "hg bd(10209)" - "unknown command 'bd(10209)'. I guess the alias is configured correctly, cause I can run hg log -r "bd(10209)" without exception. But then I of course don't get a list of the branches but all the included revisions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Roger - mea culpa, mixed revsetalias and global aliases - "New predicates (known as "aliases") can be defined, using any combination 
of existing predicates or other aliases." (from `hg help revsets`). Thus - only command with revsets support can use revset with function bd()

Comment: Ok. If I get you right, your original snippet (thanks for that!) only works to get the belonging changesets (hg log...)? To get the "distinct" branches they belong to, I need to parse them out on my own?

Comment: @Roger - no, my code return list of branches... OK, I see - I overoptimized it and must do it simpler for using inside log. Edited version added in answer

Comment: That won't show if the changeset is part of default (has been merged with). Thanks for all your help but I go with the hg contains extensions - it does what I want out of the box.